# sql weird comparison of numeric strings

Tags: sql

During an AsyncTask i pass among others a numeric string w1:

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("weight1", w1));
```

to following php script:

```
<?php

require("config.inc.php");
$query_params = null;

    $query = "  SELECT  onoma01 , epitheto01 , email01 ,username1,startPoli1, finalPoli1, 
    eidosmetaf1, weight1 , depDate1 , depTime1, tilefono01 
 FROM customer ,registration1 
 where   
 ( :sp1='empty' or customer.startPoli1 = :sp1) and 
 ( :w1='empty' or customer.weight1 < :w1) and 
  (  :em1='empty' or customer.eidosmetaf1 = :em1)  and 
  (  :fp1='empty' or customer.finalPoli1 = :fp1)  and 
  (  :dD1='empty' or customer.depDate1 = :dD1)  and 
 (customer.username1 = registration1.username01 )";    

    $query_params = array(

        ':sp1' => $_POST['startPoli1'],
        ':w1' =>  $_POST['weight1'],
        ':em1' => $_POST['eidosmetaf1'],      
        ':fp1' => $_POST['finalPoli1'],
       ':dD1' => $_POST['depDate1']               
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error2. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    $results = array();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $results[] = array(

     'onoma' => $row['onoma01'],
        'epitheto' => $row['epitheto01'],
        'email' => $row['email01'],
        'username1' => $row['username1'] ,
        'startPoli1' => $row['startPoli1'],
        'finalPoli1' => $row['finalPoli1'],
        'eidosmetaf1' => $row['eidosmetaf1'], 
        'weight1' => $row['weight1'] ,
        'depDate1' => $row['depDate1'],
        'depTime1' => $row['depTime1'],
        'tilefono1' => $row['tilefono01']   

    );  
    }

    echo json_encode(array('select_itin_results' =>$results));

?>
```

I ask from database to return rows that includes weights less than w1. My db includes weights :

```
(100 , 200 , 350 ,2000)
```

When i set w1 = 400, it returns All above numbers including 2000. It seems that it compares the two numbers number by number ( 4 of 400 is greater than 2 of 2000). How come that; (Note that weight column in database is of varchar type. T tried to change to int with no effect. Also i tried to cast $_POST['weight1'] as a int but nothing. Thanks

Comment: You're doing comparisons in SQL and not PHP, so this is not a PHP comparison problem. And of course if you use varchars to store numbers, the database may do comparisons as strings also. You can cast the values to numbers and then do the compare.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [documentation of `execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

> An array of values with as many elements as there are bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are treated as **`PDO::PARAM_STR`**.

This causes MySQL to use lexicographical comparison, and, as you noted, 400's 4 comes before 2000's 2. You can control the type the values are bounded as by using [`bindValue`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php):

```
# Prepare the query
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

# Bind values
$stmt->bindValue(':sp1', $_POST['startPoli1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':w1', $_POST['weight1'], PDO::PARAM_INT); # Bind as int!
$stmt->bindValue(':em1', $_POST['eidosmetaf1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':fp1', $_POST['finalPoli1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':dD1', $_POST['depDate1'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

# Execute with the bound parameters
$result = $stmt->execute();
```